# Refreshing Dialog In Flutter with Bloc

Tags: flutter, dialog, bloc, flutter-dialog

So I'm trying to pick a date with a [DatePicker](https://pub.dev/packages/date_range_picker) package from inside a `showDialog` using [Bloc](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/).

Here's the code that shows the `Dialog`:

```
onPressed: () {
   showDialog(
     context: context,
     barrierDismissible: true,
     child: _buildEditDialog(context, arguments),
   );
},
```

And here's the `Dialog`'s content:

```
void _openCalendarPicker(BuildContext context, SearchHotelArguments arguments) async {
    final DateTime dateTimeNow = DateTime.now();
    final List<DateTime> picked = await DateRagePicker.showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialFirstDate: arguments.checkInDate ?? dateTimeNow,
        initialLastDate: arguments.checkOutDate ?? dateTimeNow.add(Duration(days: 1)),
        firstDate: dateTimeNow,
        lastDate: dateTimeNow.add(Duration(days: 365 * 10)));
    if (picked != null && picked.length == 2) {
      context.read<HotelChangeParamsBloc>().setCheckInDate(picked[0]);
      context.read<HotelChangeParamsBloc>().setCheckOutDate(picked[1]);
    }
}
```

Now, the issue here is that from a `Dialog` I open a popup with the `DateRangePicker`, pick the `Date` and submit it but on the `Dialog` the date stays the same as it was previously. And if I close and re-open the `Dialog` I can see that there was a change in the date. So the `Dialog` is not refreshing the data by itself(unless I re-open it).

Does anyone know how I can refresh the Dialog with the new `Date` from the `DateRangePicker`?

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
If you're interested in adhering to the intended Bloc pattern, you wouldn't be firing a regular function from your dialog. That's why I said 'assuming you're emitting a new state'.

Ideally it would be

```
context.read<HotelChangeParamsBloc>().add(UserSelectedDateEvent(setCheckInDate(picked[0])));
```

In that example `UserSelectedDateEvent` is an event that passes in a `DateTime` object that gets emitted to an updated state.

That event would hit the `mapEventToState` method in your Bloc, emit a new state, and if you wrap your first dialog in a `BlocBuilder` as mentioned below, it will show the updated date

Original answer:

Assuming that your `setCheckInDate()` method is emitting a new state in your `HotelChangeParamsBloc`, you just need to wrap your first dialog in

```
BlocBuilder<HotelChangeParamsBloc, HotelChangeParamsBlocState>
```

Then within that, display the updated date with `state.yourBlocVariable.toString()`

Without the `BlocBuilder` theres nothing telling it to rebuild so it won't show the updated state until you close and rebuild it.

Comment: So, even if I have a BlocConsumer on the `build` override method I must have the BlocBuilder anyways?

Comment: If you mean you have a `BlocConsumer ` on whatever page you're building, then yes. The page doesn't build the dialog. `showDialog` does, and it has its own build method that does not share context with where ever it's being called from. So in your case if you want that first dialog to update in the way you describe, it needs its own `BlocBuilder` or `BlocConsumer`. I tested it before I posted that answer a few days ago, it works.

Comment: @Loren.A Could you provide a working example of wrapping the dialog in BlocBuilder? I tried this and am receiving a "Could not find the correct Provider above this BlocBuilder" error.

Comment: @most200 you should start your own question for that with your code posted, and paste the link here and I'll have a look.